# Button clicked to activate JOptionPane.showOptionDialog stays clicked after close

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, joptionpane

I feel like I have done the heavy lifting, and now I am stuck on what should be the easy part, closing my pane. Cans somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I think these are the applicable bits, but I am happy to add more if needed. Thanks!

I have a JOptionPane.showOptionDialog that does some complex stuff. I have a Translate button:

```
private void jButton25ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
  //Translate
```

that starts this panel:

```
     int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, xlf_myPanel, "Navigate Segments",
            JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
            null, xoptions, null);
```

And it does stuff (all works great so far):

```
     System.out.println(myglobal+" source: " + xlf_xField.getText());
     System.out.println(xlf_varig+"target: " + xlf_yField.getText());
     PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("x-files/temp/"+xlf_varig+"-.txt");
     out.println(xlf_yField.getText());
     out.close();
```

And I do some switching

```
       switch( result ) { 

        case 0:
        // Next selected
        myglobal +=1 ;  
        runnavigate("n/a moved this into runtransform", "x-files/out/tmx.xml", "x-files/xsl/xliff2tmx.xsl");
        textfield.setText(String.valueOf(myglobal));
        break;

        case 1:
        // Previous selected
       myglobal -=1 ; 
       runnavigate("n/a moved this into runtransform", "x-files/out/tmx.xml", "x-files/xsl/xliff2tmx.xsl");
       textfield.setText(String.valueOf(myglobal));
       break;

        case 2:
        // First selected
        myglobal = 0 ;  
       // jButton26.setEnabled(true);
        runnavigate("n/a moved this into runtransform", "x-files/out/tmx.xml", "x-files/xsl/xliff2tmx.xsl");
        textfield.setText(String.valueOf(myglobal));
        break;

        case 3:
        // Last selected
       myglobal = mylastglobal ; 
      // jButton25.setEnabled(true);
       runnavigate("n/a moved this into runtransform", "x-files/out/tmx.xml", "x-files/xsl/xliff2tmx.xsl");
       textfield.setText(String.valueOf(myglobal));
        break;    

        case 4:
        // Done selected
        //result.dispose(); // not working - this says cannot dispose int
        System.out.println( "Done chosen" );
        break;

        case JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION:
        // User closed the box.  Nothing selected.
        System.out.println( "Dialog Closed" );
        break;

    }
```

but when I hit the "Done" button, the Translate button stays clicked. How do I get it to properly close?

Comment: Your `result` is an `int` which is a primitive data-type and you're calling `dispose()` on it. You cannot do that. The compiler is saying something and it is correct! Why do you want to `dispose()` the `result`? Just remove that statement and it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Do you mean remove the dispose()?  I did, as you can see in my sample code, by commenting it out. That leaves me with a button that says pushed, which is what I am trying to solve. Can you help me understand how to get the button to be un-pushed?

Comment: Solved. It was part of the code I did not show:

     xlf_myPanel.add(jButton25);

I was adding the same button to the panel that the button was calling.

I removed it, and the Done button now works splendidly.